# windows batch to convert bytes to GB

Tags: batch-file, size

How do I convert the result from bytes to Gigabytes?  See this script for an example:

```
@echo off

set file=C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\%username%.ost

%1 %0 :: %file%
set len=%~z2

echo %len%  %username% >>"C:\Desktop\size.txt"
```

Comment: Or if is > to whatever size ... send a message on a txt?

Answer (score 2):

As Michael says in his answer, batch can do math computations via `SET /A`. But the computations are strictly limited to integers; there is no native floating point math. And the integers are represented internally as signed 32 bit integers. So the maximum possible number in bytes equates to ~2 Gigabytes. There are batch routines that have been written to handle large numbers, but I wouldn't recommend using them.

The formula for converting bytes to Gigabytes is simple enough:

```
Gigabytes = Bytes / 1024 / 1024 / 1024
```

In a pinch, you could do hybrid scripting and let batch call powershell to do the math.

```
for /f %%N in ('powershell %~z2/1024/1024/1024') do set len=%%N
```

But that is extremely slow and inefficient. You would be much better off to simply write your entire script in a scripting language that supports floating point - perhaps PowerShell, VBScript, or JScript.

Comment: Thanks man...Bu what I can do to make the console doesn´t display on screen?

Comment: @chesare - I don't understand your comment/question. When I execute a statement like in my answer, I don't see any output to the screen as long as ECHO is OFF.

Answer (score 2):

You may use this method:

```
set len=%~z2
set /A GB=%len:~0,-3%/1024/1024
```

That is equivalent to this formula: GigaBytes = Bytes / 1000 / 1024 / 1024. The numeric result is practically the same as the original formula, but this method allows to correctly convert file sizes of more than 2000 GB.

If you want to get the result with two decimal places, use this method:

```
set len=%~z2
set /A GBtimes100=%len:~0,-3%/1024*100/1024
echo %GBtimes100:~0,-2%.%GBtimes100:~-2%  %username% >>"C:\Desktop\size.txt"
```

Antonio

Comment: I like that your solution, but if you do the math like this
(((100000000000/1024)/1024)/1024)=93.~
(((100000000000/1000)/1024)/1024)=95.~
In my case a 2gb difference is somewhat essential.